# Ambiguous truth value of series in float dtype comparison

Tags: python, pandas

```
coverage_actual = coverage_agg.loc[coverage_agg["brand"] == brand, "coverage"]
coverage_diff = abs(coverage_actual - coverage[brand])
            if coverage_diff > 0.1:
                error = True
```

This sounds like a very silly question, but I am not able to understand why exactly my if statement is causing an error, even though the comparison is between two float values.
Please help.
Thanks in advance, and really sorry if the issue is very silly.

EDIT:

```
"coverage": {
                    "brandA": 0.6,
                    "brandB": 0.6,
                    
            }
```

[image]

When I tried to see the dtype of coverage_diff , it came out to be float.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `coverage_diff` is not a number but a Series (as the error says). So when trying to evaluate:

`if coverage_diff > 0.1` you don't have a single boolean outcome, but possibly a Series of boolean outcomes. This is, again, what the error is telling you. And - as per the error and suggested fix - you can use `[np.any][1]` to test whether any of the rows of the Series evaluate to `True`.

Comment: I understood the error statement, but I am unable to comprehend why is the coverage_diff taken as a Series in the first place. When I go into breakpoint() debug mode, I get the dtype of coverage_diff as float only. I attached screenshot above now

Comment: The __dtype__ of coverage_diff is float64. coverage_diff is a _Series_. If it was a float it wouldn't have a `dtype` function. Use `type(coverage_diff)` if you want to see the type of object you're dealing with.